# Multiple domains with Nginx, Varnish and Django all return the same cached page

Tags: django, nginx, caching, varnish

I am trying to configure a second domain for an existing project which was previously just using one. But Varnish always returns the cached page from the first domain. So when I visit the second domain I see the content of the first domain. My configurations is as follows:

Note:

- 99% of the configuration was already there
- I changed the domain names and removed some SLL configurations for this post to be more clear.
- Both domains use the same html page but slightly different content.
- I am noob regarding nginx and varnish.

NGINX

```
server_tokens off;                                                                                             
resolver 127.0.0.53 ipv6=off;                                                                                  
upstream django_app_server {                                                                                   
    server unix:/home/test/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;                                                 
}                                                                                                              

#http redirect too https.                                                                                      
server {                                                                                                       
    listen 80 default_server;                                                                                  
    server_name _;                                                                                             
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                                      
}                                                                                                              

server {                                                                                                       
    server_name existingdomain.com newdomain.com;                                                                                                                                                                 
    listen 443 ssl default deferred;                                                              

    # match with actual application server                                                                     
    client_max_body_size 10M;                                                                                  
    keepalive_timeout 60s;                                                                                     

    # proxy the request through varnish before sending it to gunicorn.        
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
    }
}
server {

    listen 8000;
    server_name existingdomain.com newdomain.com;
    root /home/test/www;

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60;
        proxy_read_timeout 60;
        proxy_set_header Host existingdomain.com; #changed to $host but results in 127.0.0.1 instead of domains
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass http://django_app_server;
    }

    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout 60s;
}
```

VARNISH

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import directors;

acl purgers {
    "localhost";
}

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8000";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    # uncruft
    unset req.http.User-Agent;
    unset req.http.Accept;
    unset req.http.Accept-Language;

    # Normalize the query arguments
    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

    # Fix client IP forwarding
    # Note: this expects Varnish to be behind upstream that sets this securely
        if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }

    # allow purge
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip ~ purgers) {
            return(purge);
        } else {
            return(synth(403, "Access denied."));
        }
    }
    elif (req.method == "BAN") {
        if (client.ip ~ purgers) {
            # assumes the ``X-Ban`` header is a regex
            ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.http.x-ban);
            return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
        } else {
            return(synth(403, "Access denied."));
        }
    }
    # only head/get
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return(pass);
    }

    # kill cookies for everything else
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return(hash);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # keep for lurker bans
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;

    # do the gzip dance with nginx
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "^text/" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "^application/json") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s || beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store|private") {
        # mark as "Hit-For-Pass"
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s || beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store|private") {
        # mark as "Hit-For-Pass"
        set beresp.ttl = 1m;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    }
    # stop server error hammering
    if (beresp.status == 500 || beresp.status == 502 || beresp.status == 503 || beresp.status == 504) {
        set beresp.ttl = 5s;
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        return (deliver);
    }
    # stop 404 hammering
    if (beresp.status == 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 10s;
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        return (deliver);
    }
    # don't cache 40x responses
    if (beresp.status == 400 || beresp.status == 401 || beresp.status == 402 || beresp.status == 403) {
        set beresp.ttl = 5m;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        return (deliver);
    }

    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    set beresp.grace = 2m;
    set beresp.ttl = 5m;

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # for internal use only
    unset resp.http.x-url;

    # debug info
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "hit";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "miss";
    }
    # set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;

    # cleanup headers
  # cleanup headers
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_purge {
    # only handle actual PURGE HTTP methods, everything else is discarded
    if (req.method != "PURGE") {
        # restart request
        set req.http.X-Purge = "Yes";
        return(restart);
    }
}
```

I tried:

- Changed NGINX: `proxy_set_header Host existingdomain.com;` to `proxy_set_header Host $host;`
- Changed NGINX: 2 server configurations listing to port 8000 for both domains
- Changed VARNISH: 2 backend configurations for both domains

What do I want:

- Eventually I want 2 different domains and several subdomains who all need its own varnish cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# proxy the request through varnish before sending it to gunicorn.        
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
}
```

You are not passing any details to varnish. So Varnish can't figure out which domain to work with. Maybe something like

```
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:6081;
```

Plus like others have stated you need to update what the host you are sending to `gunicorn`

Comment: Yes I did change the $host to Gunicorn before but indeed forgot to pass it first to Varnish. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The following config line:

```
proxy_set_header Host existingdomain.com;
```

Sends the same `Host:` header for both domains.

It should be:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

The other answer mentions `$hostname` variable which is incorrect, because it stands for machine name. Whereas you want `$host` as this is equal to value of `Host:` header from the client.

Comment: I tried that but this way $host seems to become 127.0.0.1 instead of the current visiting domain name like existingdomain.com or newdomain.com, I guess because varnish runs on 127.0.01. It breaks the website because 'Django sites' cant differentiate between the domains. For example request.get_host() returns 127.0.0.1

Comment: As in the answer by @Shawn C., you also need to propagate `Host:` and other headers in the `server` responsible for TLS termination. Add `proxy_set_header` directives to the server block with `listen 443 ssl`.

Answer (score 0):

The following Nginx setting causes Varnish to only serve pages from `existingdomain.com`, even if other hosts are requested:

```
proxy_set_header Host existingdomain.com;
```

Varnish uses both the *URL* and the *hostname* to identify objects in cache. When you hardcode the hostname to `existingdomain.com` in Nginx, you'll always end up with the same content.

Please change this setting to the following value:

```
proxy_set header Host $hostname;
```